# Dependency property is not updating the view

Tags: c#, observablecollection, dependency-properties, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl that is binding to an ObservableCollection "MenuButtons".
In the ItemsControl, I want to add some Buttons programmatically with Dependency Properties.

My problem is that the values I pass are not updated. The default values are displayed in the view.

**C#**

```
  private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = DataContext as UflMainWindowViewModel;
        vm.MenuButtons.Add(new UflMenuButton { IconText="Test123", Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["UflMenuButtonStyle"] });
    }
```

**C#** UflButtonClass

```
public class UflMenuButton : Button
{
    public string IconText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconText", typeof(string), typeof(UflMenuButton), new UIPropertyMetadata("default", new PropertyChangedCallback(IconTextChanged)));

    private static void IconTextChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UflMenuButton button = (UflMenuButton)sender;
        button.IconText = (string)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

with the following Style:

**WPF**

```
<Style x:Key="UflMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:UflMenuButton}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:UflMenuButton.IconText),RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that pass the value?

Comment: The value gets passed in the Button Click event in the first code block by the following command: `IconText="Test123",...`

Comment: The problem is "After added a button, the button isn't displayed". Correct?

Comment: nope, the button is displayed but the value in the button's text block is not "Test123". It contains the default value of the DependencyProperty "default"

Comment: Try `<TextBlock Text="{Binding IconText}"...`

Comment: Then no text at all - not even the default value - is displayed. I therefore think that the binding works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236190/discussion-between-tisonus-and-vernou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the first ancestor of type `UflMenuButton` :

```cs
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IconText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UflMenuButton}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This work, but I assume a more elegant way exists.